# Weighted flow accumulation: using deforestation as weight?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flow-accumulation, forest-ecology, runoff

Right off the bat: if a small river has 10% of its upstream catchment deforested, and a big river has 5%, I want that small river to have higher output values. But now it won't because of how much more flow accumulation the big river has.

---

I need to figure out which rivers in a certain area have the most potential influence from upstream deforestation.

So, I used ArcGIS Pro to calculate flow accumulation with my deforestation raster with pixel values ranging from 0 - 1.

The result, of course, still is biased towards bigger rivers with more flow accumulation.

Any idea on how I can separate flow accumulation from deforestation values?

Comment: Divide by catchment area.

Comment: @FelixIP That's a very straightforward way which I didn't think of somehow! Do you reckon there is any way to do that within the flow accumulation calculation?

Comment: Flow accumulation without weight raster is catchment area at every cell raster.